# Kotlin. Не получается преобразовать массив Pair в Map

Tags: kotlin

Хочу сделать вот такое:
(из массива Pair преобразовать первый элемент каждой пары в String, а затем весь массив в Map)

```
fun function(vararg array: Pair<Any, String>) =
        array.forEach { it.first.toString() }.toMap()
```

Выдает 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все-таки стоит полный текст ошибки привести. Ваше сокращение лишило нас 50% информации.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja дополнил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял, вот то что вы желаете:

```
fun function(vararg array: Pair<Any, String>) =
    array.map { it.first.toString() }
```

`forEach` просто прогоняет по элементам массива, ничего не возвращая.

Второй вариант:

```
fun function(vararg array: Pair<Any, String>) =
    array.map { Pair(it.first.toString(), it.second) }.toMap()
```

Comment: это возвращает ArrayList<String>, а мне нужно Map<String, String>.

Comment: См. второй вариант

Comment: да, вот так заработало, спасибо!